# MapKit: trace route

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I have a MapKit with current location and one MkPointAnnotation. I need to trace route between these points.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //esconder navBar
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *zoomButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle: @"Onde Estou?"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target: self
                                   action:@selector(zoomIn:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = zoomButton;

    UIBarButtonItem *typeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle: @"Tipo"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target: self
                                   action:@selector(changeMapType:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = typeButton;

    double lat = -21.21258;
    double lng = -47.816802;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate;

    Coordinate.latitude = lat;
    Coordinate.longitude = lng;

    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationPoint.coordinate = Coordinate;
    annotationPoint.title = @"Ribeirão Shopping";
    annotationPoint.subtitle = @"Ribeirão Preto - SP";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint]; 

    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = lat;
    newRegion.center.longitude = lng;
    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with native API, you can use - through JSON - HTTP services provided by [Google Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

Comment: MKDirections API was added in iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

Use MKDirectionReqeuest and MKDriectionResponse. MKDirectionResponse has MKRoute that will help you to plot the line.

Documentation can be found here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsRequest_class/)